# ROS Tutorial - Nothing happens when running "Writing an action server and client (C++)

Tags: ros2, tutorial, action-server, action-client

I think I've followed the instructions for this ROS Tutorial and have the following files plus config file changes:

```
- ros2_ws
    - src
        - custom_action_cpp
            - CMakeLists.txt
            - packages.xml
            - src
                - fibonacci_action_client.cpp
                - fibonacci_action_server.cpp
            - include
                - custom_action_cpp
                    - visibility_control.h
```

Everything appears to compile
I have sourced the environment
When running the code using `ros2 run custom_action_cpp fibonacci_action_client` nothing happens. Executing Ctrl+C I see

```
[INFO] [1709070325.252217058] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
[ERROR] [1709070325.253261878] [fibonacci_action_client]: Action server not available after waiting
[INFO] [1709070325.253455348] [fibonacci_action_client]: Sending goal
```

Any suggestions as to what I have done wrong?
CMakeLists.txt updated with client and server changes from tutorial

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics,* Jevers. What I don't see in your file structure is a CMakeLists.txt file. Do you have one, and does it reference both the client and server cpp files? It also looks like your command starts only the client, and your error is that there's no server - what happens if you run `ros2 run custom_action_cpp fibonacci_action_server` before starting the client?

Comment: @chuck thank you, starting the server was the answer, thank you